# Two apps in one URL in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-apps

I try to link two apps to one URL. I found an example, where that can be possible with "include" command and two separate "urls.py" for each app.

So, I tried to do that, but it still only one app works on page... Please, help.

My main URL config:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
 # Examples:
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 url(r'^', include('joins.urls')),
 url(r'^', include('item.urls')),
 url(r'^items/get/(?P<item_id>\d+)$', 'item.views.item', name='item'),
 url(r'^(?P<ref_id>.*)$', 'joins.views.share', name='share'),
)
```

My first app URL config:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
 # Examples:
 url(r'^', 'joins.views.home', name='home'),
)
```

My second app URL config:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
 # Examples:
 url(r'^', 'item.views.items', name='home'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your entire approach is mistaken, unfortunately. A view is responsible entirely for responding to a URL and returning a response. It simply doesn't make sense to talk about having two views at a single URL.

If you need functionality provided by two apps within one URL, then think about abstracting the shared functionality into a utility method, or a template tag, or a context processor.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dollar sign to the regex:

```
url(r'^$', 'joins.views.home', name='home'),
```

Without the `$` the `^` regex matches all urls.

Of course the `item.views.items` will not work anyway (django executes the first matched url) but other views from `item` app will work just fine.

Comment: Thx, but I dont understand, what means "other views". I have two apps. One of them (joins) - subscribe form, another (item) - list of blogs. All, what i want to do - see them both at one page... So, how I can do that?

Comment: My view for 'item':

    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http.response import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def items(request):
 return render_to_response('items.html', {'items': Item.objects.all()})

def item(request, item_id):
 return render_to_response('item.html', {'item': Item.objects.get(id=item_id), 'comments': Comments.objects.filter(comments_item_id=item_id)})

Comment: You can't have two views at the same url.  Django runs the first view for the matched url.

Comment: @s_spirit You want two views for one URL?  To do that write a view that gets both models, pass both to your render function and make a template that displays what you want from each.  Making two urls the same will only do what the first match does

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this I think:

```
 url(r'^joins/', include('joins.urls')),
 url(r'^items/', include('item.urls')),
```

see this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

@s_spirit You want two views for one URL? To do that write a view that gets both models, pass both to your render function and make a template that displays what you want from each. Making two urls the same will only do what the first match does –  joel goldstick 2 hours ago